# Simple/basic database design problem (with relationships)

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin

It's been years since I've done anything with SQL databases (and I was never more than a novice). I think I've messed something up and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I have 3 tables:

- services (as in cable TV, satellite TV, and streaming TV), with
  columns for ID and Name
- channels (as in CBS, ESPN, HBO, etc.) with
  columns for ID and Name
- service_channels with columns for ID,
  service_id (foreign key), and channel_ld (foreign key)

Apparently I messed up when creating the relationships because when I go into phpMyAdmin to insert rows, when I click the dropdown for service_id, it lists all the rows in services AND all the rows in channels. The same is true for the channel_id dropdown. Can anyone suggest what I may have done wrong and how to go about fixing it?

EDIT: I'm not sure exactly what info to post about the database. Currently, there's just a little bit of test data in it, so I'll just publish a full export. (I hope that's not a violation or anything.)

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.7
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Aug 29, 2018 at 04:11 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB-cll-lve
-- PHP Version: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `cxyz77uc_tvchannels`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `channels`
--

CREATE TABLE `channels` (
  `ID` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(24) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `channels`
--

INSERT INTO `channels` (`ID`, `Name`) VALUES
(1, 'ABC'),
(2, 'CBS'),
(3, 'Fox'),
(4, 'NBC'),
(5, 'PBS');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `services`
--

CREATE TABLE `services` (
  `ID` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(48) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `services`
--

INSERT INTO `services` (`ID`, `Name`) VALUES
(1, 'YouTube TV'),
(2, 'Sling Orange'),
(3, 'Sling Blue'),
(4, 'Hulu'),
(5, 'Fubo');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `service_channels`
--

CREATE TABLE `service_channels` (
  `ID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `service_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `channels`
--
ALTER TABLE `channels`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `services`
--
ALTER TABLE `services`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `service_channels`
--
ALTER TABLE `service_channels`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `service_id` (`service_id`),
  ADD KEY `channel_id` (`channel_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `channels`
--
ALTER TABLE `channels`
  MODIFY `ID` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `services`
--
ALTER TABLE `services`
  MODIFY `ID` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `service_channels`
--
ALTER TABLE `service_channels`
  MODIFY `ID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `service_channels`
--
ALTER TABLE `service_channels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `service_channels_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `services` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `service_channels_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`channel_id`) REFERENCES `channels` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Please show us the DDLs for the tables you describe.